# Finite axiomatization of second-order NBG

Tags: set-theory, axioms, foundations

First-order NBG set theory is finitely axiomatizable. The proof of this basically shows that the axiom schemas, in the presence of the other axioms, can be reduced to a finite set of cases, and are hence equivalent to a finite set of axioms.

Is this equivalence also valid in second-order NBG? Or does the reduction to a finite number of cases only work for definable predicates (e.g. the first order axiom schema)?

Comment: What do you mean by "second-order NBG", exactly?

Comment: NBG with the axiom schemas replaced with a second order axiom. Is this term ambiguous?

Comment: Well, that is at least somewhat ambiguous (it's not obvious what second-order axiom you're using, given that an essential feature of NBG is that its comprehension schema is restricted to formulas without class quantifiers--is "second-order NBG" the same thing as "second-order MK"?).  But in any case, if second-order NBG does not have any axiom schemas, it's unclear what you mean by your question.

Comment: I guess there is probably only one reasonable choice for the second-order axiom, and no hope of distinguishing second-order NBG from second-order MK.  I still don't know what your question is--are you asking whether second-order class comprehension is equivalent to the finitely many first-order axioms used in NBG?  (In that case the answer is obviously not, since the latter are only equivalent to first-order class comprehension.)

Comment: Sorry, I meant each axiom schema is replaced with one second order axiom - the same as second order ZFC. So second order NBG would be NBG, but with the second-order axiom of comprehension and the second order axiom of replacement. I thought MK would be different from NBG because it allows class comprehension. Is the terminology not standardized though?

Comment: Both NBG and MK have a class comprehension schema; the difference is that MK allows formulas with class quantifiers in the schema.  That distinction is lost if you replace the schema with a second-order axiom saying "every collection of sets is a class".  (Also, NBG usually isn't stated with a replacement schema, since you can just use a class quantifier, and the necessary generality follows from the comprehension schema.  This doesn't really make a difference for anything, though.)

Comment: Hm, alright. I can see how NBG's class comprehension is only different from MK's in the first order version. Does there exist a name for the second order theory you get by replacing the first-order class comprehension in either theory with the second-order axiom?